# How to speed up simple Pandas for/if loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a fairly simple loop that runs fine, but takes much longer than I think it should (~5 minutes).

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if pd.isnull(df['Date'][i]):
        df['Date'][i] = df['Date'][i-1]
```

The purpose here is to fix date and times in a data file I have that is structured where the first row for each day has the text for the date, but all others are blank.  I'm simply looking to see if the value is null or not, and if it is, setting it to the previous value.

[image]

Is there a more Pandas-y way to do this more efficiently?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use forward filling `ffill`

```
df.Date.ffill(inplace=True)
```

**Demo**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Date=['Wed', None, None, 'Thr', None, None],
        Time=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    ))

df

   Date  Time
0   Wed     1
1  None     2
2  None     3
3   Thr     4
4  None     5
5  None     6
```

Then

```
df.Date.ffill(inplace=True)

df

  Date  Time
0  Wed     1
1  Wed     2
2  Wed     3
3  Thr     4
4  Thr     5
5  Thr     6
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy.  Thanks!